# Dictionary extension for using @AppStorage

Tags: swift

I understand I need to make `Dictionary` conform to `RawRepresentable` when using a dictionary with @AppStorage. Below is the furthest I got.

```
extension Dictionary: RawRepresentable where Key == String, Value == String {
    public init?(rawValue: String) {
        guard let data = rawValue.data(using: .utf8),  // convert from String to Data
            let result = try? JSONDecoder().decode([String:String].self, from: data)
        else {
            return nil
        }
        self = result
    }

    public var rawValue: String {
        guard let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(self),   // data is  Data type
              let result = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) // coerce NSData to String
        else {
            return "[:]"  // empty Dictionary respresented as String
        }
        return result
    }

}
```

The extension compiles. But when I declare an empty dictionary it didn't work:

```
@AppStorage private var data :  [String:String] = [:]
```

The error message is `Missing argument for parameter #2 in call`

What's wrong with the codes?

Comment: Unrelated but the string representation of an empty (JSON) dictionary is `"{}"`

Comment: @vadian, good catch!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the string key for the storage:

```
@AppStorage("data") private var data :  [String:String] = [:]
```